# Hide iframes during load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to hide `iframes` during the load to prevent a white rectangle over the background color.

My actual js

```
$( '#my_frame' )
    .css( 'visibility', 'hidden' )
    .attr( 'src', '/my_new_page.html' )
    .one( 'load', function () {
        $( this ).css( 'visibility', 'visible' )
    });
```

The problem is when in the `iframe` I catch the `onbeforeunload` event and I prevent the switch of the page, because of the `iframe` never fire the `load` event so it remains hidden.

How can I do that?

PS: i tryed to catch the `unload` event before hide the page, but it never fires when changing the src.

[**jsFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5o38bx27/)

Comment: the `.one` it's for catch the event only one time ;-)

Comment: Your code works http://jsfiddle.net/tbptgzhm/ :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski - it doesn't work if I prevent the page changing catching the `onbeforeunload` event inside the iframe

Comment: @BojanPetkovski - I have added an jsFiddle that display the behavior

Comment: Here you are , no white rectangle http://jsfiddle.net/5o38bx27/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some tries I found a working method:

```
$frame
  .load( function () {
    this.style.visibility = 'visible';
    this.contentWindow.onunload = function ( e ) {
      this.window.frameElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    };
  });
```

when the iframe loads I show it and I attach to it's window an unload event that hides the iframe.

Comment: Thanks a lot.you really made my day

Answer (score 0):

Set the css of the iframe to display: none, and then do a $(document).ready() and change the css to display block within it. should keep it hidden until the DOM loads, then display it.

Comment: this function is attached to a button, so when I click it the iframe will be hidden the change the src attribute and when loaded display it again. The problem is: when I change the `src` and I prevent the changing of the page form inside the iframe it remains hidden